# calling c# webservice using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

When i try to call c# webservice using jquery ajax I get `Internal Server Error` and if i call it from browser directly i get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: newDonor Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

the following is the web method

```
[WebMethod]
public void newDonor(localDonor donor)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("donors");

    table.CreateIfNotExists();
    Donor newDonor = new Donor(donor.FullName, donor.Mobile);

    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(newDonor);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);}
```

the following is the ajax method of jquery

```
  var userInput = {
                FullName: "Lakshman NEW",
                Mobile: "1122004455"
            };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "addDonor.asmx/newDonor",
            data: JSON.stringify(userInput),
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (error) {

                alert(error.toString());
                }
            });
```

What could be the mistake, everything seems to be fine.. ???

Comment: The error is very clear: *System.InvalidOperationException: newDonor Web Service method name is not valid.*, go to the asmx test page and look for the needed request, it will show you an example of routes and headers.

Comment: everything is working fine if there are no  input parameters. i get this issue when i send a json input as parameter.

Comment: Gosh, you're sending json, WebMethods are SOAP, not json...

Comment: You need to set your C# Method static ! public static void newDonor(localDonor donor)